# Warning when counting values in session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

Since upgrading to PHP 7.2 I now get this warning when trying to get the number of values in a PHP session

```
Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in
```

The code I have tried using to get the number of values is

```
$numSelected = count($_SESSION['selectStandards']);
```

and

```
$numSelected = sizeof($_SESSION['selectStandards']);
```

I thought that a php session was an array but it seems my understanding was incorrect but what I'm not sure about is how to convert a session into an array.

Having said that, will leaving my code as it is cause me problems further down the line?  My existing code is working exactly as it is.

This is the var_dump of $_SESSION['selectStandards']

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(6) "107732" [1]=> string(6) "107733" [2]=> string(6) "107731" [3]=> string(6) "107734" }
```

Comment: that specific element in the array is not an array

Comment: @Andreas I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that

Comment: Do `var_dump($_SESSION['selectStandards']);` and you will see it is not an array or an object that is countable. PHP sessions are arrays, but the values they contain can be anything.

Comment: @JohnConde will converting the session into an array fix it?

Comment: The session already an array. *That value inside the session is not*. And I can't say as I don't know what that value is or what will happen if you change its type.

Comment: @JohnConde thats what is confusing me, I can get the values from the session by using echo $_SESSION['formOptions'][3]; etc.

Comment: You *really* need to post the results of `var_dump($_SESSION['selectStandards']);` in your question.

Comment: @JohnConde added :)

Comment: That's an array so [you shouldn't be getting this error](https://3v4l.org/RLaiV). Does this item exist in your session at the time you are trying to count its items? You're missing something somewhere.

Comment: @JohnConde thank you, that helped me suss it.  When the page is loaded the session is initiated but it is empty.  Once I added values to it on another page and went back to the original page, it worked and the error was gone

Comment: @John the actual problem is poorly expressed and this page is not likely to help others.  Please consider voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Why not check if it exists and if it's indeed an array, which one could count?

```
$numSelected = isset($_SESSION['selectStandards']) && is_array($_SESSION['selectStandards']) ? count($_SESSION['selectStandards']) : 0;
```

Comment: It definitely exists because I am pulling values from it further down in my code which is working.  I just need to find a way to get the number of values in the sessions.  count and sizeof are returning the values I am expecting but I understand it is not the correct way to do it

Comment: That'll get rid of the error but may not give them the results they expect

Comment: What even is `$_SESSION['selectStandards']` ??

Comment: *Exactly*. If they would add the output of `var_dump($_SESSION['selectStandards']);` to their question we could better help them.

Comment: Well... if it's CSV, one would need to `explode()` before `count()`.